# OpenCV cvGetTickCount() for RTSP streaming

Tags: c++, opencv, rtsp, rtp, ip-camera

I am streaming from a MJPEG media server over RTSP

OpenCV has a function called cvGetTickCount()

My question is: Does this method return the difference in RTP timestamps (from the rtp header) between frames? Or does OpenCV just look at the FPS and tick frequency and return a constant value each time?

When I print the results from cvGetTickCount() the values look too perfect. I recall previously manually decoding a RTSP stream and getting results with some variance

I am struggling to find any proper documentation about this method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"cv2.getTickCount function returns the number of clock-cycles after a reference event (like the moment machine was switched ON) to the moment this function is called.", see [Reference](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dc/d71/tutorial_py_optimization.html). You can use this function you measure the runtime based on the system clock. But this has nothing to do with the RTSP stream timestamp. 
I would suggest the VLC api or ffmpeg api to get that timestamp.

Comment: "The cv::VideoCapture class would be the right place for that implementation" Does this functionality exist in OpenCV? Otherwise I'll give live555 a try next since they have a nice RTSPClient example

Comment: No, it does not exist